# Automatically create a gravatar account through a third party site

Tags: php, gravatar

Is it possible to automatically create a gravatar account, based on the registration data that a user on my site submits? I like gravatar, but I do not want to make my users register twice

Comment: I'm not sure if it is fair to register users at a third-party site without their explicit permission - if it is _possible_ to do this, then make sure you have your users' active consent.

Comment: Leaving any technically challenges aside for the time being: You can't accept the Gravatar terms and conditions on behalf of your users, so no.

Comment: You _could_ proxy them to your site.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, you could use curl for manipulating the Gravatar site with get and post requests and parsing the result. This way you could use the data provided by the user on your site to create an account on Gravatar.

Note that is they have some kind of captcha or equivalent, this will not work directly without some kind of captcha forwarding.

Finally, I wouldn't really actually do this but I'm just saying that's it is *possible*.

Comment: I should think `Gravatar` uses email link authentication too, and so the user will need to be actively involved in the secondary sign-up.