# Bulk registration of gravatar

Tags: wordpress, gravatar

I'd like to register all of our staff to have [gravatar](https://en.gravatar.com/)s. They are an unreliable bunch, so if I *ask* them to sign up for one it would take about 6 months to get to 50% completion.

I *could* use selenium to drive the website to sign everyone up, then simultaneously reconfigure the spam filter to collect all the confirmation emails, *then* go back over all of those emails and confirm the accounts. But that feels like a very dirty hack.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11812482/automatically-create-a-gravatar-account-through-a-third-party-site) mentions a similar need, but there isn't an answer.

Does anyone know if there is a better way to sign up for a lot of gravatar accounts in one go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gravatar protects itself from spamming their registrations system by using email confirms.

Besides, you're breaking their TOS by trying to automate signups.

Best thing to do is take the management approach - this is more of a management issue than programming - and tell your staff they are required to get a Gravatar, or 1) they don't get their daily Gummy Bears, or 2) they're fired.

Comment: I feared that this might be the problem. If only i wielded that kind of power!